# More time and space efficient way to access value of dictionary in stack without knowing its key?

Tags: python, dictionary, stack

I ran into this problem in trying to solve a string candy crush problem. Here's MY version of the explanation of the problem:

> Given a string `"DAABBBBABCC"`, return a string where 3 or more
>   consecutive letters or characters are removed. Note that the once you remove a
>   section of the string, any new combinations that make 3 or more
>   consecutive letters should also subsequently be removed.
>
> Hence `"DAABBBBABCC"` when reduced becomes "`DAAABCC"` which is further
>   reduced to `"DBCC"` [the returned string].

I approached this problem by maintaining a stack of letter dictionaries. If I saw letter 'a', I would add it to the stack as `{'a': 1}` and if the next letter was also `'a'`, I would increment this value otherwise I would push to the stack a dictionary of the new letter say `{'b': 1}`. Now in order to increment the count of the repeating character, I would need to check the count of the last letter dictionary added to the stack. What is the most efficient way of accessing the count in Python without knowing what the key is in this last dictionary that was pushed?

For the purposes of explaining the question, here's an example. The stack was built after iterating over a string `"hhaaa"`

```
>>> stack
[{'h': 2}, {'a': 3}]
```

I have thought of 2 ways but they seem somewhat laborious. Which one is more efficient than the other and is there a shorter way of getting the count? **NOTE**: you don't know what the key of the last dictionary is and the dictionary is will always have one key-value pair.

The 1st approach is:

```
>>> value = list(stack[-1].values())[0]
>>> value
3
```

The 2nd approach is:

```
>>> value = next(iter(stack[-1].values()))
>>> value
3
```

Which of the two approaches is more time and space efficient and is there another approach that beats the two given the approach of using a stack of dictionaries to solve the problem?

Comment: @martineau - the code involved in the question is in Python that's why I had Python in the title.

Comment: There's no need to use second code. Its both faster and efficient to use first code.

Comment: Does it have to be optimal? Can `"AAABBBAA"` be reduced to `"AA"` (3 As, then 3 Bs) instead of `""` (3 Bs, then 5As)?

Comment: heretoinfinity: Everyone already knows your question is related to Python from its tag—so it's redundant to both specify it in the title and tag it similarly. The instructions at the beginning suggest you **tag** your Python questions accordingly. Also see the meta question: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: @martineau. Thanks. I completely forgot about the tag.

Comment: heretoinfinity: No worries as it's not a serious problem...and you're certainly not the only one who does it. It's just one of my pet-peeves because so many questions that get asked here do it (especially on the weekends).

Comment: @chepner - `"AAABBBAA"` is to be reduced to `"AA"` and not `""`

Comment: @DecaK- could you post an answer so I can upvote it?